Export LDAP attributes in LDIF file with LDIFWriter (Python
I'm trying to export data from an LDAP entry in an LDIF file.
connexion.search(search_base=base_dn, search_filter=filtre_ldap, attributes=['*'], search_scope=SUBTREE)
entry = connexion.entries[0] # I have only one result
dn = entry.entry_dn
attributes = entry.entry_attributes_as_dict
with open(output_ldif, 'w') as ldiffile:
    writer = LDIFWriter(ldiffile)
    writer.unparse(str(dn), attributes)

I have this error:
  File "C:\Outils\Python310\lib\site-packages\ldif3.py", line 193, in unparse
    self._unparse_attr('dn', dn)
  File "C:\Outils\Python310\lib\site-packages\ldif3.py", line 137, in _unparse_attr
    self._fold_line(line.encode('ascii'))
  File "C:\Outils\Python310\lib\site-packages\ldif3.py", line 103, in _fold_line
    self._output_file.write(line)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

I don't understand... Is the good method?

What do you mean by "Is the good method?"?

Hi. I wonder if I used the right functions.

The error
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

needs to be interpreted backwards – it means the module is trying to write bytes into the file, which implies that the file must have been opened in binary mode open(..., "wb") so that it would have a .write() method that accepts bytes.

Thank's you very much, I don't have this error ... but an another one :
File "C:\Outils\Python310\lib\site-packages\ldif3.py", line 131, in _unparse_attr
encoded = base64.encodestring(attr_value)
AttributeError: module 'base64' has no attribute 'encodestring'
Python 3.10.11 / ldap3 2.9.1 / ldif3 3.2.2 / pip 24.0 / pyasn1 0.6.0 / setuptools 65.5.0
